# Accessing hidden field and room

Tags: android-room

When i add room to my project my logcat has many warnings like:

> Accessing hidden field
> Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->mCloseGuardLocked:Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;
> (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)

Why i get this warnings and how to fix it?

[image: logcat]

Comment: Any solution for this? I am also getting this error and very annoying

Comment: @Teo i didn't find any solutions. If you found please post your solution

Comment: any solutions? I got the same

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems like it was Android Studio issue. After update Android Studio to 4.1.2 i don't see this issue anymore.